# Can/Should I hide the details of Error 403: org_internal in google login?

Tags: google-api, authorization, google-api-php-client, google-oauth, google-signin

I am using Google's login API for a project that needs to be internal to my organization. When I tested to see what happens if I try to login with an account that is not part of that organization, this error showed up:

[Error message image on https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnXNw.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnXNw.png)

This error shows the client id provided by my API panel on my developer account.

Is showing that information safe? If not, what could I do to hide it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client identifier [1] and everything else on the error page is not considered a secret. The error message has two uses: to lock your app down for internal usage and to allow users to use that information to escalate to you, the developer, or their admin that they need access to a particular app if they have a legitimate need for it. For the latter, it is important for users to be able to identify apps, typically using the client ID.

[1] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.2